# Changing product.GetSeName() to Product.SeName Nopcommerce 2.40

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, seo, sitemap, nopcommerce

Hello I am working Nopcommerce 2.40 and trying to replace all `product.GetSeName()` to `product.SeName` as I am inserting SeName at the time of uploading and creating product for the sake of optimization, as my catalog has grown big and also its taking too much time to generate sitemap as `product.GetSeName()` is being called for each product. Would that affect any other functionality. My `seoSettings.AllowUnicodeCharsInUrls` is always `false` so no worry with that condition. Please share your thoughts and if there will be any future issue with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to your question. But why do you replace it? I think you can simply modify existing GetSeName() method implementation to return product.SeName. This way only one change is required instead of all places where GetSeName() method is used

Comment: I suggested that to my boss as well, but he don't even want to call that function, cant do much with it! ;)

Comment: It'd save a database call for each entity which is always a good thing with many entities. Another approach is to generate URLs from domain objects using the product name, for example.